# Repeating tk_choose.files to import multiple .csv files multiple times

Tags: r

I am using `sapply(tk_choose.files)` to produce an interactive window where I can choose which .csv files (multiple) to import. I then do some basic data manipulation so that the mean of one particular column can be plotted using ggplot.

So far my code looks something like this:

```
>tfiles <- data.frame(sapply(sapply(tk_choose.files(caption="Choose T files
(hold CTRL to select multiple files)"), read.table, header=TRUE, sep=","), c))

>rfiles <- data.frame(sapply(sapply(tk_choose.files(caption="Choose R files 
(hold CTRL to select multiple files)"), read.table, header=TRUE, sep=","), c))
```

I have then calculated the mean of a particular column for both `tfiles` and `rfiles` so that I could plot `100-tfiles-rfiles`.

While this is working fine for one set of data, I would like to now import more sets of data, preferably also using `sapply(tk_choose.files)`. Essentially I need to get `t/rfiles1`, `t/rfiles2`...and repeat the data manipulation process after that, so that I could get a plot of multiple sets of data. I have no idea how to do this without having to copy and paste my code!

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am very new to R so I am really stuck, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quick question, aren't you losing the column names with your above command? Wouldn't it be better to use `ldply` from package `plyr` for  something like `tfiles <- ldply(tk_choose.files(), read.csv)`? Also, I would advise against using `tk_choose.files` as it lacks reproducibility. Instead create list of file names by manipulating `list.files(pattern="\\.csv")`

Comment: Sorry if it a naive question, but what does "lacking reproducibility" specifically mean?

Comment: It means that someone else (or even you at the later date) who use the script may not be able to choose the same files, in the same order,  to reproduce the results you originally have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the files in the working directory are as follow:

```
all.files<-list.files(pattern="\\.csv")

all.files
[1] "R01.csv" "R02.csv"  "R03.csv"  "R04.csv" "T01.csv" "T02.csv"  "T03.csv"  "T04.csv"
```

And you wish to call tfiles1 as merged data of T01 and T02; tfiles2 as merged data of T03 and T04

```
T <- grep("T", all.files, value=T)

T
[1] "T01.csv" "T02.csv"  "T03.csv"  "T04.csv"

t.list <- list(T[1:2], T[3:4])

all.T <- lapply(t.list, function(x)ldply(x, read.csv)) 
for (i in 1:length(all.T)) assign(paste0("tfiles", i), all.T[[i]]) #this will produce tfiles1 and tfiles2 in your R environment.
```

Comment: Thanks- although this is not exactly what I am trying to do here... rather than creating a list of all the T files, I would like to be able to manually choose which files to use- so something like an interactive dialog box.

Comment: If you insist... `get_files <- function() ldply(tk_choose.files(), read.csv)`. then either get files with `tfiles1 <- get_files()` or assign on loop like `for(i in 1:2) assign(paste0("tfiles", i), get_files())`